# Record Label Instrumentals

Tags: instruments, history

Does anyone know if record labels keep a copy of every instrumental of every song produced by their producers? I know that there are places online that have regenerated or reproduced instrumentals of popular songs but like I stated before, do record labels have all instrumentals of all the songs created.

Comment: I have often wondered about this because it seems that people doing remixes would need access to the original instrumentals, if not the individual tracks/stems. My guess would be the labels can get them easily from the artist/producer if someone asks to do a remix. Hip-hop is another story because they often release instrumentals as B-sides anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It's a long time since I was actively involved in the record industry... but back in the 80's we would always do a separate mix without lead vocals, in case it was ever needed for the occasional TV show where the track would be on playback but the vox would be live.

The chances are this is still a sensible practise.

Motown even went so far as to release a huge swathe of their most popular back catalogue [60s, 70s, 80s] as karaoke in the past few years - original tracks, minus lead vox, plus lyrics.
So it would seem they too always followed the practise - either that or they went back to the original multi-tracks & remixed the whole lot; which sounds a bit excessive for the money they would make from karaoke sales.